# Disable Firestore's browser logging

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a web app that uses Firestore. Today I noticed that it is logging debug/etc info to the browser console. I don't recall seeing this before.

Here are some of the lines from the browser console

```
log:connect() index.js:32
log:connect() bypassed channel-test. index.js:32
log:connectTest_() index.js:32
log:GetForwardChannelUri: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel/test?VER=8 index.js:32
log:TestConnection: starting stage 2 index.js:32
log:Buffered index.js:32
log:Test Connection Finished index.js:32
log:connectChannel_() index.js:32
log:GetForwardChannelUri: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel?VER=8
```

I am using Vue, from a template based on the `vue-cli webpack` template.

This is happening both when I run the local dev server and from the production-built SPA.

Is there any way to disable this logging? Nowhere in the documentation mentions any kind of logging and Google didn't have anything either. I don't like it, because if I want to look for any actual output, I have to wade through Firestore's logging that I don't care about. I also don't like that it seems to log all data it returns to the console as well.

If it makes a difference, I am using the `firebase v4.6.0` library from NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with earlier versions of Firestore. I've since migrated to v4.12.1 and it no longer occurs.

I've since learned about the [setLogLevel](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore?authuser=0#setLogLevel) method from Jeff Padgett.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('silent');
```

Other valid values are `'error'` and `'debug'`.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseFirestore.setLogLevel(silent);